# Give a Value from HTML to Servlet

Tags: html, forms, jsp, security, servlets

I have a delete Dialog which gives the ID of the event to the Servlet with a Input as hidden like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="${event.Id}">
```

But this isn't really safe ... is there a better solution? I don't know a better way just with JSP and HTML.

Comment: What you see as not safe there?

Comment: You cant edit this value very easy ... so a guest can delete any post